# Extended signed multiplication

Tags: assembly

I have recetly programmed a unsigned extended multiplication in assembly. I used the mul instruction and stored the words in revserse order. And the asnwer was perfectly right.
But now I'm worry about the signed extended multiplication and unable to come to any final result that how should statt and end. 
Please help or give the idea how it can be done ?

Comment: lets start with what instruction set are you interested in?

Comment: After that show the code